# Dynamically put element in the middle of screen based on media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a responsive website that can suit to any type of devices screen
the Problem is now every device has different pixels, and I want it to dynamically put lets say a div into a middle of screen.

Currently I am now using margin-left: xxpx to adjust it..
And the result is different for every devices which is either for smartphone or phablet or tablet..

Should I use "%" for the margin-left instead? and if not, can anybody tell me the better way to do it?

Comment: Media queries won't really help you here.  Media queries can only tell you yes/no.  They can't give you screen dimension back in terms of an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say.

Typically you can position the element absolute and then do `left:50%;` and set `margin-left` to negative 50% of the width of the element(ie if your element is 250px you would set `margin-left:-125px;`). If the element has a specified width you can do `margin:0 auto;` otherwise `text-align:center;` might work as well, it depends on your code.

Answer (score 0):

`margin:0 auto;` will center the div. You may also specify a `width` for the div, otherwise it will take 100% width.

You can change with media queries the width, (or use a % based width) and keep the `margin: 0 auto`.

Example:

```
.center {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 30%;
}
```